# Don't open "source" link on revisions list in new tab

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, revisions-list

I noticed today that the "source" link, when you look at [a post's revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/267901/revisions), opens in a new tab. This seemed strange to me - I tried to go back several times before realizing why it wasn't working.

I don't really have a problem with links opening in a new tab (although I prefer using the same tab), but it seems inconsistent. Every other link I can find on the page (or the entire network, for that matter) opens the target in the current tab. So why is this one link being treated differently?

Could it be changed so that it's consistent with other links, or is there some reason why it's better to keep it as-is?

Comment: I've just tried this on Firefox 41.0.1 and it opens in a new div.

Answer (score 1):

I add great value to consistency, so that would be a yes for this feature request.

However, in this specific case I *often* find it quite useful. When I view the source of a revision, I usually do that to edit the question (or a specific revision for that matter). That action is on the page *source* would navigating away from when copying the source. (This could be fixed by a simple *Copy to clipboard* link in the revisions.) Implementing this feature request means I often have to *Control-click* instead of just click.

For now, I am not sure which of the arguments is more important.

Comment: If the page doesn't open it in a new tab you can still do so through the browser (right-click, or I think some browsers or OSs use modifier keys).